# How to convert {x -> 4} to simply 4?

Tags: equation-solving, output, conversion, input

I am using the Solve function to obtain two solutions for a quadratic, then I want to use those two solutions as input for something else but I can't because they are in the form of (x->number}

```
potential = 5/2*x^2
solut2 = Part[Solve[potential == 40, x], 2]
```

The output that comes out is

```
{x -> 4}
```

but I need simply 4 to be the input in some other functions.
Thank for your help!

Comment: `Solve` and its kin returns lists of `Rule`s and those are meant to be used with `Replace`, e.g. as in `x /. Solve[potential == 40, x][[2]]`.

Comment: `Part[...,2]` $\to$ `Part[..., 2, 1, 2]`.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users, esp. https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18706/4999